# openSuse: how to get rid of annoying "Authentication Required" dialog from auto-update

Tags: gnome, opensuse, polkit, packagekit

This annoying dialog "Authentication Required" started to pop up recently, just after every login to KDE, demanding root password to refresh system repositories. After a minute or so it disappears on it's own, followed by a "update failed" tray notification, which also disappears soon. It's not a blocker, just annoying and looking unprofessionally. Please, how to get rid of this?

It must be something to do with KDE/Gnome interoperability because:

- it started to appear only after I had installed Gnome alongside my primary KDE
- no Authentication Required pops up when login to Gnome
- the dialog looks like it is from Gnome (KDE has a differently looking password UI)

[image]

The pop-up dialog says (in case you cannot see the screenshot above):

```
Authentication is required to refresh the system repositories.
Action: Refresh system repositories
        org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
Vendor: The PackageKit project.
polkit.subject-pid: xxxx
polkit.caller-pid:  xxxx
```

Comment: Some googling suggests that this is a bug that has been fixed. Can you try updating, or try [one of these two workarounds](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/502754-quot-Authentication-is-required-to-refresh-the-system-resources-quot?p=2677468#post2677468)?

Comment: Thank you Nick. I knew about that link but the advice seems to be dated. I wasn't able to find "Apper Monitor" or a "Configure Desktop -> Startup and Shutdown -> Service Management"

Answer (score 4):

I've received some useful advice on openSUSE forum:
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/531458-Authentication-Required-how-to-get-rid-of-this-annoying-dialog-after-every-login
Credits to *nrickert*.

It's most likely not an Gnome/KDE interoperability issue. When I followed the process, entered password, and what followed looked like a standard KDE System Update check.

Simplest workaround is to switch off regular updates in KDE:
*Right click on the tray (bottom right). Click on "System Tray Settings". Uncheck the box for "Software Updates".*

[image]

[image]

https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/531458-Authentication-Required-how-to-get-rid-of-this-annoying-dialog-after-every-login